# mysql table problem

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

If I wanna provide a free guestbook service via php+mysql,I have two choices,

1. store all message in one database
2. create a table for each free user.

If I have registered 1000 users and 100000 message,

A table have 1500MB VS 1000 tables are 0-3M each ,

which one is faster? and why ? Or better idea?

thanks

Comment: Faster for what? Better for what?

Comment: "System optimization" doesn't mean anything. The best schema strategy depends on how you _use_ the tables, which you're not explaining. (Although a schema with a variable number of tables (other than temporaries) is quite often a sign of bad design).

Answer (score 4):

One table 1500MB will definitely be better in space & organisation. Because each table creates aditional space overhead.

In short, go with one table. That's the only valid solution. MySQL and other DBMSs are not made for such abuse you want to perform.

Comment: +1 just make sure that the table is indexed correctly. It's best to have a table `users` with a primary key, say `user_id`, and another table `messages` with a primary key, `message_id` and a foreign key `user_id`

Comment: So what if the table have 5GB and 500,000,000 rows?

Comment: Same. Doesn't change the situation. If you are going to split, you tables will use **even more** space.
5GB table is nothing special, I see it every day.

Comment: Firstly they probably won't. Secondly it won't matter; that's what databases are for. `messages` will, as far as I can tell be only 2 or 3 columns, which will be very quick to scan. Our largest tables are around 90Gb and I access then in 0.01 s using the primary key.